# ClientAbortException in streaming video with spring-content and spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, video-streaming, spring-content-community-project

I'm using spring-content for streaming video in Spring Boot and use video tag in HTML5. I am facing this problem when pause or forward video in browser:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:364) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copyRange(StreamUtils.java:203) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.writeResourceRegion(ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.java:159) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:531) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at internal.org.springframework.content.rest.controllers.StoreRestController.getContent(StoreRestController.java:144) ~[spring-content-rest-1.1.0.M3.jar:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

also when using download manager this exception occurs. I tried to use FileSystemResource instead of spring-content but ClientAbortException is still happening

my config for spring content:

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
public class StoreConfig {

    public File fileSystemRoot() throws IOException {
        return new File("local_storage/video");
    }

    @Bean
    public FileSystemResourceLoader fsResourceLoader() throws Exception
    {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(fileSystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

@StoreRestResource(path="videosrc")
public interface VideoStore extends Store<String> {
}
```

Comment: what is the best way to streaming video in spring boot with forward capability?

Comment: This is a false negative.  The client can abort for a number of reasons and there is nothing the server-side can do about it when it decides to do so and is also not detrimental to the functioning of the server.  Spring Content now suppresses this exception by defaut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problem happen when the browser "get bored" (time out).

Problem like this can happen when the browser is waiting for more data and no more data is comming.

In this case you didnt attached the `@RequesGet` function, I can't explain what the is the  problem in your case.

But this is an example for video streaming made in spring..

```
@RequesGet(path = "/videos/get/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ResourceRegion> getFullVideo(
                                                @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                                                @PathVariable("id") String id ) throws Exception {
      
    File file = videoLogic.getFileById(id);
    UrlResource video = new UrlResource("file:"+file.getAbsolutePath());
    ResourceRegion region = resourceRegion(video, headers);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
             .contentType(MediaTypeFactory
                    .getMediaType(video)
                    .orElse(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM))
             .body(region);
}

private ResourceRegion resourceRegion(UrlResource video , HttpHeaders headers ) throws Exception {
        long contentLength = video.contentLength();
        Optional<HttpRange> range = headers.getRange().stream().findFirst();
        if (range.isPresent()) {
            long start = range.get().getRangeStart(contentLength);
            long end = range.get().getRangeEnd(contentLength);
            long rangeLength = Math.min(1 * 1024 * 1024, end - start + 1);
            return new ResourceRegion(video, start, rangeLength);
        } else {
            val rangeLength = Math.min(1 * 1024 * 1024, contentLength);
            return new ResourceRegion(video, 0, rangeLength);
        }
    }
```

Code credit: [melgenek](https://melgenek.github.io/spring-video-service)